# NotSupportedException on EndGetRequestStream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
public async static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request, Dictionary<string, object> post)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse>();

    try
    {
        request.BeginGetRequestStream((arReq) =>
        {
            var stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(arReq);//throw NotSupportedException

            writeMultipartObject(stream, post);
            stream.Close();

            request.BeginGetResponse((ar) =>
            {
                var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                tcs.SetResult(response);
            }, null);

        }, null);
    }
    catch (Exception we)
    {
        tcs.SetException(we);
    }

    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

when i post something, it no works..=.=
**var stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(arReq);//throw NotSupportedException**
tell me why?  ToT.................

System.NotSupportedException ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object sendState)

Comment: The method is like "GET" or "POST", and apparently, the server does not support the method you are using, at least not on that URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced similar behaviour (on Windows Phone only) and got it working by explicitly disposing the stream you're writing to.
So try to add

```
stream.Flush();
```

before, and
    stream.Dispose();

after your

```
stream.Close();
```

statement and see if that helps.

Apparently, the behaviour of the networking stack in .Net is different dependent on the platform your code runs on, due to the fact that the .Net framework is "redeveloped" for each platform.

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Kristof.

Comment: Thank you.  This solved a similar problem of mine.  I was getting this error for GetResponseAsync().  Per your tip,putting the stream in a using block solved the problem.